# DH67BL Motherboard beep 6 times

Tags: motherboard

Last week I bought a computer with the following specs:

Motherboard: Intel DH67BL

RAM: 2x4GB AMD 1600Mhz

Processor: Intel i7 3770 3.4Ghz

Harddrive: 2TB Seagate Sata 3

Every time I turn on my computer, it beeps 3 times and after 2 seconds beeps 3 times again.

Does my computer have a problem or is normal the beeping on start?

Comment: Since you havn't bothered to do the basic checks, let me get you started: [3 beeps = Bad memory](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/cs-010249.htm).  Take it back to where you bought it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While one beep during startup might be normal regarding the BIOS, multiple beeps definitely aren't.

The documentation of a mainboard usually shows the meaning of certain "beep-sequences".

In your case the error description reads:

```
Memory error
```

for the pattern:

```
On-off (1.0 second each) three times, then
a 2.5-second pause (off), the entire pattern
repeats (beeps and pause) until the system
is powered off.
```

See: [Intel DH67BL manual](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/19487/eng/DH67BL_ProductGuide01_English.pdf)

I guess you have built in incompatible or defective memory. Try removing one memory bar or a different RAM.
Returning the mainboard would not be the first step I would try.